# SQLite connection in PowerShell 7

Tags: c#, powershell, sqlite, .net-core, user-defined-functions

PowerShell-7+

I want to create a SQLite *User-defined Function (UDF)* as shown in [User-defined functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/user-defined-functions). The examples are in C# which I never use but would like to make it work in PowerShell. Unfortenately I cannot instantiate the *SqliteConnection* in PS. Here's my trivial snippet:

```
Add-Type -LiteralPath "path\to\Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll"
using namespace Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
$con = New-Object Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection -ArgumentList "Data Source=hello.sqlite"
```

which throws this Exception

```
New-Object: Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' threw an exception."
```

Should I use this alternate form? it also fails with same error:

```
$con = [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection]::new("Data Source=hello.sqlite")
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' threw an exception."
```

I'm getting confused! What's wrong with the instanciation?

Comment: Where did you obtain `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll`?

Comment: I used dotnet CLI (dotnet-6.0.101). I instantiated a new project and installed _`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`_ : `dotnet new console; dotnet add package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite; dotnet build`.

Comment: I tried to load assemblies in different ways, as described in [https://blog.ironmansoftware.com/daily-powershell-2/](https://blog.ironmansoftware.com/daily-powershell-2/) just to be sure, but with no better result! No clue?